# Python: Replace while loop to update rows of a dataframe with shift values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

Index   Branch  Flag   Sequence
1         X      0        A
2         X      1        B
3         X      1        C
4         X      1        D
5         X      0        E
6         X      1        F
7         X      0        G
8         X      0        H
9         Y      0        I
10        Y      1        J
11        Y      1        K

I need to update the Sequence column as follows:
For each Branch, all Sequences with a Flag equal to 1 should have the same value than the Sequence of the row with a Flag equal to 0 located above (the first row with a Flag equal to 0 above). I have managed to do this using the While loop below but as my dataframe has around 2M of rows I would like to find a "Pythonic" way to do this more efficiently.

I have solved this with a While loop but would like to find a pythonic way to do this to improve the efficiency (around 250s for 1.7M rows with the while loop).

```py
While np.logical_and(df['Flag']==1,df['Sequence'] != df['Sequence'].shift(1)).any()):
  df['Sequence']=np.where(df['Flag']==1,df['Sequence'] != df['Sequence'].shift(1),df['Sequence'].shift(1),df['Sequence'])

df dataframe

Index   Branch  Flag   Sequence
1         X      0        A    
2         X      1        B  
3         X      1        C  
4         X      1        D  
5         X      0        E  
6         X      1        F  
7         X      0        G  
8         X      0        H  
9         Y      0        I  
10        Y      1        J  
11        Y      1        K 


Output:

Index   Branch  Flag   Sequence
1         X      0        A    
2         X      1        A  
3         X      1        A  
4         X      1        A  
5         X      0        E  
6         X      1        E  
7         X      0        G  
8         X      0        H  
9         Y      0        I  
10        Y      1        I  
11        Y      1        I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I posted earlier was indeed incorrect.

Try this:

```
df.Sequence[df.Flag == 1] = np.nan
df.Sequence.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ Index ║ Branch ║ Flag ║ Sequence ║
╠═══════╬════════╬══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ X      ║    0 ║ A        ║
║     2 ║ X      ║    1 ║ A        ║
║     3 ║ X      ║    1 ║ A        ║
║     4 ║ X      ║    1 ║ A        ║
║     5 ║ X      ║    0 ║ E        ║
║     6 ║ X      ║    1 ║ E        ║
║     7 ║ X      ║    0 ║ G        ║
║     8 ║ X      ║    0 ║ H        ║
║     9 ║ Y      ║    0 ║ I        ║
║    10 ║ Y      ║    1 ║ I        ║
║    11 ║ Y      ║    1 ║ I        ║
╚═══════╩════════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have tested your solution but unfortunately it has only updated 1 A / E / I and not as described in the result above all with 1 instruction. Did you mean that your solution is to loop with the 'mask' solution instead of using np.where ?

Comment: @Jon1 thanks for pointing that out. I was testing it on IDLE, and I probably ran that statement multiple times, which is why it worked for me. I've modified the solution. See if it gives you the intended result. **Note**: I haven't considered groups here (based on `Branch` column). So, let me know if that causes any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tested and it seems to be ok for me. I should use it with my dataset and will keep you up to date. I will then of course validate your very pythonic solution. It seems so simple when you have it :-)

Comment: Brillant solution, as far as I know this is a real pythonic solution: simple and efficient ! 215s saved for my 1.8M rows. Some will find it obvious but one need to think the Python way to find it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jon1 welcome :).. Please note what I said about groups, though. This solution doesn't consider it. This has worked for you because at the beginning of each group there's a `0` in the flag. This might be how your data is structured. However, if, say, the `Y` branch rows didn't have any `0`s in the `Flag` column, the last sequence value of the preceding group will get filled here. Just wanted to point that out. Glad it helped you.